# TOP 10 Values in DAX Aggregation

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I want to show top 10 customers with highest sales amount in DAX.
please let me know why this formula doesn't work, and what is the best syntax?!

```
DEFINE
MEASURE InvoiceLines[Sales] = sumx(InvoiceLines,InvoiceLines[Quantity]*InvoiceLines[UnitPrice])
EVALUATE

TOPN(10,
SUMMARIZE(
    Customers,
    Customers[customerID],Customers[CustomerName],
    "Sales" ,InvoiceLines[Sales]
    )
, InvoiceLines[Sales],DESC
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this; the easiest is to create a simple measure to calculate sales amount in DAX:

```
Total Sales := CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]))
```

Then you can simply use this in the "Top N" filtering option on the "Visual Level Filters" pane in the .pbix, you simply drop in the measure and choose 10 as your N parameter.

A more complicated way that I've done it in the past, using DAX:

```
Top 10 Customers :=
VAR RankingContext =
    VALUES ( 'Customers'[CustomerName] )
VAR TopNumber = 10
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Total Sales],
        TOPN ( TopNumber, ALL ( 'Customers'[CustomerName] ), [Total Sales] ),
        RankingContext
    )
```

I hope this helps!! (I'd go with option #1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, however my environment is DAX studio over powerpivot in Excel, not PowerBI. I could not get any result when adapting your second suggestion.

Comment: Ouch!! I am sorry about that.